# How to add multiple Headers with the same name containing different values

Tags: go, http-headers

My Go application is trying to modify (add/remove) the incoming Request/Response headers. I want to add multiple headers with the same name and different values. However I don't see how this is possible as the http Header object coming from the Request/Response object is a map and hence will not allow duplicate keys. Is there a way to achieve this?

**Example**: I want to add 2 headers with the key header1

```
name=header1
value=["value1","value2"]
```

The resulting headers should be

```
header1="value1"
header1="value2"
```

instead of

```
header1="value1,value2"
```

Comment: You cannot do that. HTTP mandates to combine headers if possible.  Additionaly: It is not necessary as both variants have the same meaning.

Comment: Agree that both the variants have the same meaning, but what if the server is expecting them as a separate header? What if there is a software that is acting as a mediator and needs to send to the backend server as 2 separate headers. Surely we can argue about the usefulness of it but in the practical world, things sometimes do get weird.

Answer (score 2):

An [http.Header](https://godoc.org/net/http#Header) is a map of string slices. The slice elements represent different values for the header named by the map key.

Use [Header.Add](https://godoc.org/net/http#Header.Add) to add multiple values for a given header.

```
h.Add("Header1", "value1")
h.Add("Header1", "value2")
```

The header is written to the network as:

```
Header1: value1
Header1: value2
```

An alternative is to set the map element directly:

```
h["Header1"] = []string{"value1", "value2"}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @thwd. Your reply is useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want, based on your question, becuase the output you claim to want is not a valid header at all.

But what I can tell you is that using the standard `net/http` package, your output will be:

```
Header1: value1
Header1: value2
```

See it [in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zD3tZHYN2Ga).

Note that, according to the HTTP spec, this is exactly equivalent to:

```
Header1: value1, value2
```

Comment: My requirement is that I need to modify the incoming Request before sending it to the backend. Hence I can not use the http Writer like you have used in the example which can give the output in the required format. Is there a way to modify the Request Headers to achieve the add multiple headers with the same key?

Comment: The default behavior is to add multiple headers with the same key. I don't understand what you're asking.